# `{n}` iteration meta character after posix class in regex

Tags: regex

I am learning regular expressions. I have some doubts relating to that example :

I'd like to find all the files with conventional extensions in names. This works:

```
ls | grep '\.[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]]$'
```

but this does not:

```
ls | grep '\.[[:lower:]]{3}$'
```

As far as I understood the `{n}` iteration meta character results in matching with pattern that has exactly `{n}` occurrences of preceding character. Doesn't it work with POSIX classes? Or am I making some silly mistake here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [POSIX basic (BRE)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), you need to escape the braces for this to work:

```
ls | grep '\.[[:lower:]]\{3\}$'
```

In POSIX extended (ERE), this requirement has been dropped, and ERE also finally adds alternation (`|`) to regular expressions (although some tools which use BRE do support alternation via `\|`).

Comment: Why do we need double square brackets?

Comment: @thefourtheye Because that’s how named character classes in POSIX work.

Comment: @thefourtheye: For example, if you wanted to construct a character class that contains `.`, `0` and lowercase ASCII characters, you could use `[.[:lower:]0]`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh I get it now. `[:lower:]` is the same as our range `a-z` in other languages. Thanks for clarifying :-)